# how assign EntityConnectionStringBuilder.Metadata sqlite

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite

I'm trying to instantiate a EntityConnectionStringBuilder but it fails when I assign EntityConnectionStringBuilder.Metadata, here's my string:

ee.Metadata = @"res://*//Data//EntityModel.csdl|res://*//Data//EntityModel.ssdl|res://*//Data//EntityModel.msl";

Where "Data" is a folder. If I don't have the file in a folder, it works fine though.